# Promisifying a third-party JS library with minimal code overhead

Tags: functional-programming, typescript, wrapper

## Context and Existing Code

I am trying to "promisify" a third-party authentication library (auth0-js) written in JavaScript. Right now it uses callback functions and there are no plans to expose an `async/await` friendly API. So, I'm writing a wrapper, to avoid [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) in my own code.

Here's a callback factory function `cb` which is actively used for creating Promises.

```
import * as a0 from "auth0-js";

export function cb<TResult>(
  resolve: (reason: TResult) => void,
  reject: (reason: a0.Auth0Error) => void,
): a0.Auth0Callback<TResult> {
  return (error, result) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(result);
}
```

And here's an example of a wrapper class.

```
import * as a0 from "auth0-js";
import { cb } from "./cb";

export class Authentication {

  /**
   * Wraps the Auth0-js' `Authentication` object and exposes Promise-based methods.
   * @param wa Wrapped `Authentication` object.
   */
  constructor(private wa: a0.Authentication) { }

  public get dbConnection(): DbConnection {
    return new DBConnection(this.wa.dbConnection);
  }

  public buildAuthorizeUrl(options: any): string {
    return this.wa.buildAuthorizeUrl(options);
  }

  public loginWithDefaultDirectory(options: a0.DefaultDirectoryLoginOptions): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.wa.loginWithDefaultDirectory(options, cb(resolve, reject)));
  }

  public login(options: a0.DefaultLoginOptions): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.wa.login(options, cb(resolve, reject)));
  }

  public oauthToken(options: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.wa.oauthToken(options, cb(resolve, reject)));
  }

  public loginWithResourceOwner(options: a0.ResourceOwnerLoginOptions): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.wa.loginWithResourceOwner(options, cb(resolve, reject)));
  }

  public getSSOData(withActiveDirectories: boolean, options: a0.DelegationOptions): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.wa.getSSOData(withActiveDirectories, cb(resolve, reject)));
  }

  public userInfo(accessToken: string): Promise<a0.Auth0UserProfile> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.wa.userInfo(accessToken, cb(resolve, reject)));
  }

  public delegation(options: a0.DelegationOptions): Promise<a0.Auth0DelegationToken> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.wa.delegation(options, cb(resolve, reject)));
  }

  public getUserCountry(): Promise<{ countryCode: string; }> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.wa.getUserCountry(cb<{ countryCode: string; }>(resolve, reject)));
  }
}
```

## Question

While I'm always open to any constructive feedback, there are a few specific aspects I'll be particularly thankful for.

1. I'm a C# developer and still know too little about JavaScript/TypeScript. **If you know how to make this code look more *JS-idiomatic*, I'm all ears.** Or I can paraphrase the question as "am I going the right/common route?"
2. You can see that there is a lot of structural repetition in the code that creates Promises from callbacks (e.g. `loginWithDefaultDirectory(...)`, `login(...)`, `oauthToken(...)` functions). Not nice. **Is there a way to apply functional programming ideas here? I have a feeling that functional composition may get handy here, but I don't know how to apply it (a sign, I haven't grasp the concept yet)**
3. **Resolved** <strike>It's also easy to notice that `buildAuthorizeUrl(...)` is a *pass-through*. No callbacks here. There must be an easier way to bind one object's function to another object's function, which I don't know how to do. Very similarly, `get dbConnection()` accessor is a supposed to be a *pass-through*.</strike>

## Update 1

I figured the pass-through members can be coded very easily (one line per member):

```
 public buildAuthorizeUrl = this.wa.buildAuthorizeUrl;
```

So, point 3 is now out of question.

Comment: Should `getSSOData` use the `options` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you can avoid a lot of the structure duplication in this class. A `promisify` function would help a lot. Node has a built in [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original). Alternatively, you could write a simple method to apply the arguments and resolve when called. In vanilla JS this is simple enough.

```js
function callPromised(method, ...args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        method(...args, (error, result) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(result))
    })
}
```

Unfortunately, this method is difficult to type correctly in TypeScript. There's a proposal [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453). The best we can do now is write several overloads which gets incredibly messy with only a few parameters.

```ts
function callPromised<TResult>(method: (cb: Auth0Callback<TResult>) => void): Promise<TResult>;
function callPromised<TResult, Arg1>(method: (arg1: Arg1, cb: Auth0Callback<TResult>) => void, arg1: Arg1): Promise<TResult>;
function callPromised<TResult, Arg1, Arg2>(method: (arg1: Arg1, arg2: Arg2, cb: Auth0Callback<TResult>) => void, arg1: Arg1, arg2: Arg2): Promise<TResult>;
function callPromised(method: Function, ...args: any[]): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        method(...args, (error, result) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(result))
    })
}
```

The downside of this function is that `this` will not be bound correctly. This could be rectified by passing in a `self` parameter and would be required for your usage.

```ts
function callPromised<TResult>(method: (cb: Auth0Callback<TResult>) => void, self: any): Promise<TResult>;
function callPromised<TResult, Arg1>(method: (arg1: Arg1, cb: Auth0Callback<TResult>) => void, self: any, arg1: Arg1): Promise<TResult>;
function callPromised<TResult, Arg1, Arg2>(method: (arg1: Arg1, arg2: Arg2, cb: Auth0Callback<TResult>) => void, self: any, arg1: Arg1, arg2: Arg2): Promise<TResult>;
function callPromised(method: Function, self: any, ...args: any[]): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        method.call(self, ...args, (error, result) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(result))
    })
}

// For example
public loginWithDefaultDirectory(options: a0.DefaultDirectoryLoginOptions): Promise<any> {
    return callPromised(this.wa.loginWithDefaultDirectory, this.wa, options)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gerrit0! This is a very good answer which points to the right direction. In fact, I asked another question on SO about how to achieve what you're describing. I looked at implementations in both `promisify-js` and `typed-promisify` libraries, which are similar but not the same. Unfortunately, at this point TypeScript is still missing a lot of things related to smarter type inference. This leads to -- as you very correctly noted -- ugly, messy, and quickly growing overloads which have to be expressed upfront. Thanks again for the cool answer (I wish you saw my question a bit earlier)

Comment: And here's the link to SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552920/typescript-type-inference-in-a-generalized-promisify-function Plus the link to the related TypeScript feature https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453 Plus the link to the roadmap https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap